# Matching rows based on same user and latest date

Tags: r, date, merge, match

I have 2 different data (rentals and searchs). I want to match rentals with search based on user and time.

Example:

```
Id  Type    UserId  Time
1   Rental  1       15:35
2   Search  2       15:34
3   Search  1       15:33
4   Search  1       15:32
```

I want to find the last search before rental which made by same user.

I want result something like this.

```
Id  Type    UserId  Time    Search Id
1   Rental  1       15:35   3
2   Search  2       15:34   
3   Search  1       15:33   
4   Search  1       15:32
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `case_when` and `hm`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(lubridate)
 df %>% group_by(UserId) %>% 
  mutate(T = time_length(hm(Time)),   #We need time_length as hm returns a period object
         `Search Id`= case_when(
    n() >=2 & Type=='Rental' ~ Id[T==max(T[Type=='Search'])], #return the max where we have groups 
                                                  #with more than two obs and Type equal to Rental
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
    ))


# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   UserId [2]
     Id Type   UserId Time      T `Search Id`
  <int> <chr>   <int> <chr> <dbl>       <int>
1     1 Rental      1 15:35 56100           3
2     2 Search      2 15:34 56040          NA
3     3 Search      1 15:33 55980          NA
4     4 Search      1 15:32 55920          NA
```

However, I think it's more straightforward to separate your dataframe into two dataframes and do a normal left or right join, e.g,

```
dfren <- filter(df,Type=='Rental')
dfser <- filter(df,Type=='Search') %>% group_by(UserId) %>% 
       filter(time_length(hm(Time))==max(time_length(hm(Time)))) 

dfren %>% left_join(dfser,by='UserId', suffix = c(".Ren", ".Ser"))

  Id.Ren Type.Ren UserId Time.Ren Id.Ser Type.Ser Time.Ser
1      1   Rental      1    15:35      3   Search    15:33
```